# How to fix "TypeError: fsevents is not a constructor" react error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

While staring React app using npm start this error occurred...

I tried below things:

1. remove node_module package and reinstall
2. use yarn instead npm

3.update fsevent library using npm

still getting this error

Note: If we create react app fresh/new yarn start will work, but we close the terminal and restart using same thing  below error occurred

```
/Users/nannam/test-app-2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js:28
```

return (new fsevents(path)).on('fsevent', callback).start();
          ^

> TypeError: fsevents is not a constructor
>       at createFSEventsInstance (/Users/nannam/test-app-2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js:28:11)
>       at setFSEventsListener (/Users/nannam/test-app-2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js:82:16)
>       at FSWatcher.FsEventsHandler._watchWithFsEvents (/Users/nannam/test-app-2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js:252:16)
>       at FSWatcher. (/Users/nannam/test-app-2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js:386:25)
>       at LOOP (fs.js:1565:14)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11) error Command failed with exit code 1. info Visit
>   https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this
>   command.

Answer (score 49):

```sh
npm audit fix --force
```

It worked in my case

Comment: It worked for me, the first time i ran this command, it show me some warnings, **node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir ...**, so i re run it with sudo `sudo npm audit fix --force`

Answer (score 23):

below steps solved issue :

- step 1 :  removing `node_module` and `yarn.lock`
- step 2 :  yarn install
- step 3 :  yarn start

[image]

Answer (score 16):

This is a well-documented [issue on the react GitHub repo](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6891) with a couple of options to try.

I solved my error by re-installing the fsevents `npm i fsevents`, which worked

Answer (score 8):

The @not-a-file gave will work  only you can install the fsevents successfully。
but when I do that, I receive an error with this:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/**/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsents/.node-gyp'
```

So ,I suggest you avoid this by use something like this:

```
sudo npm i fsevents --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

And I also find this error may due to node version, when I use node 12,I can not install fsevents successfully , so I use nvm to modify my node version to v11.15.0

Comment: It was the node version for me. Downgraded to 10.24.1 from 12.18.1

Answer (score 8):

I solved with

```
sudo npm i fsevents --unsafe-perm
```

Comment: It's always great to format you answer or question well!

Comment: Arthur Menezes, please augment your code-only answer with some explanation. That helps fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free coding service. You could for example elaborate on the fine differences to the older answer by crazy_Y and what additional advantage yours provides.

Answer (score 7):

Solved it using Yarn's [selective dependency resolutions](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/)

```
"resolutions": {
  "chokidar": "^3.3.1"
},
```

as some packages in my dependencies are still on older chokidar versions < 3

Answer (score 4):

Do these simple steps. Run the following

```
rm -rf node_modules/ package-lock.json
```

and then

```
npm i
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same issue though am using MacOS the issue is kind of bug. I solved this issue by repeatedly running the commands,

- sudo npm cache clean --force
- sudo npm uninstall
- sudo npm install

One time it did not worked but when I repeatedly cleaned the cache and after uninstalling npm, reinstalled npm, the error went off. Am using Angular 8 and this issue is common

Answer (score 2):

For me, downgrading node to v11.15.0 solved the error.

Comment: Same here. Had issues running npx create-react-app on node v11.0.0 -> tried to go with v12.10.0 via nvm, got the fsevents error. Downgraded to 11.15.0 via nvm and just ran yarn, yarn start and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

remove `node_module` and `package-lock.json` and use `yarn` instead of `npm`. This saved me hours.

Answer (score 2):

I deleted the node modules package and reinstalled the node and then executed the node js commands. it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I FINALLY resolved the issue. The fsevent error occurred right after I installed bootstrap from my VS code terminal. I ended up using the react-bootstrap-github stylesheet code instead and put it in my index.html!

Answer (score 1):

I solved changed my "package.json" using this `react-scripts": "2.1.8`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I run the following command and it is working fine now, without using Yarn.

"npm audit fix"

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue in node v11.15.0 my solution was: with my "react-scripts" version in "3.0.1" I just update it to "2.1.8" and run `npm install` after. You can use this version or search for one that works for you. Another option is updating nodejs to the latest version, then remove modules and run `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we did not found any permanent resolve, but you just create that app again or use `yarn` package manager to install all modules again in your react app then run `yarn start`. that's how I solve my issue in react app.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working after running:
`$sudo npm install npm@latest -g`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue using the `ng serve` command. I tried all of the above combinations and none of them seemed to fix this issue permanently. A simple quick fix / get around for me was to close and reopen the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error `TypeError: fsevents is not a constructor` and tried all answers (remove node_modules, uninstalling/installing fsevents, sudo npm cache clean --force, sudo npm install/uninstall) listed; but nothing resolved it. For some reason, fsevents is breaking for node version >v10.x.

Regenerating lockfile resolved this issue

```js
npm i --package-lock-only
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command

```
npm install latest-version
```

Answer (score 0):

Run:
npm audit fix --force

Then, try again.

Answer (score 0):

This often happens due to the continuous update to react and npm-packages.

Try to remove your node_modules

***npm uninstall***

delete your ***yarn.lock***
this will save tons of time and if you are using npm instead if yarn
always updated.

run ***yarn install***

Answer (score 0):

After trying "npm audit fix --force" did not work , I tried:

1. Removing node_modules folder
2. npm i

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Mac. In my case, the problem with this error was the absence of Python.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71957847